# I want to view my database in android through sqlite browser

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-permissions

My data and other folders in ddms are empty due to which I am unable to view my database through sqlite browser. I am using eclipse for android. I suspect its some problem with the permissions but can't point at it.

Comment: are you testing application in device or emulator ?

Comment: device , one plus one to be specific

Comment: By default android sqlite db store in data/data/app_package directory. You can only access those folder in rooted phone or in emulator. OR for testing purpose you can put/write sqlite in sdcard and checking it. Hope it's clear you.

Answer (score 1):

you can install [root Explorer](http://www.dl.farsroid.com/app/Root-Explorer-3.3.5(FarsRoid.com).apk) on your emulator, this app can open databases also

Answer (score 0):

If you are using real device then you can't able to access **DATABASE** because you need root to access the directory.

**Solution** is to use simulator in which you can able to access **DATABASE** or use **rooted device**.